# UITableViewCell Label's Incorrectly Displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want my labels to be spaced out slightly and to have more than one line of text available.

***Cell.m*** is

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,69,69);
    float limgW =  self.imageView.image.size.width;
    if(limgW > 0) {
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y+self.textLabel.frame.size.height,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
    }

}
```

In the controller, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"Title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = object[@"Request"];
    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"ProfilePic"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon60x60@2x.png"];
    cell.imageView.file = thumbnail;
    CALayer * l = [cell.imageView layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:36.7];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:15];
    UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:12];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = cellFont2;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    return cell;
}
```

How come the 2nd line is getting abbreviated, and why are the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` so close to each other?
[image]

Comment: use custom label in the place of **cell.textLabel** and **cell.detailTextLabel**

Comment: It seems like you want a truly custom cell (which you appear to have created in `Cell`), but you're still trying to get the standard controls (`textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`) to fit your data. Instead, I'd recommend treating your new cell class as if you didn't have access to any controls and just create the ones you need yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the custom UITableViewCell,

for example:

```
@interface CustomViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UILabel *titleView;
@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UILabel *detailView;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 if(limgW > 0) {
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);

        // change this two lines
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height * 2);
        self.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    }
```